# Como verificar si Ruby on rails tiene activado el caching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cache

Estoy realizando un procedimiento para almacenar la cache en de una consulta a la base de datos en rails, pero cuanto intento probar la funcionalidad en la consola no me funciona. No guarda el registro en la caché.

Estoy usando

- Rails 5.2.2
- ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

---

Consulta a la base de datos de post

```
class PostsSearchService
  def self.search(curr_posts, query)
    posts_ids = Rails.cache.fetch("posts_search/#{query}", expires_in: 1.hours) do
      curr_posts.where("title like '%#{query}%'").map(&:id)
    end

    curr_posts.where(id: posts_ids)
  end
end
```

Consulta en la consola rails

```
PostsSearchService.search(Post.all, "lorem")
```

Resultado de la consola

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 12312
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.2)
irb(main):001:0> PostSearchService.search(Post.all, "lorem")
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NameError (uninitialized constant PostSearchService)
irb(main):002:0> PostsSearchService.search(Post.all, "lorem")
  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (title like '%lorem%')
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 18], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 18, title: "In doloremque ducimus sint.", content: "Accusamus dolores ab. Beatae accusamus eos. Omnis ...", published: false, user_id: 2, created_at: "2019-01-04 06:42:20", updated_at: "2019-01-04 06:42:20">]>
irb(main):003:0> PostsSearchService.search(Post.all, "lorem")
  Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (title like '%lorem%')
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 18], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 18, title: "In doloremque ducimus sint.", content: "Accusamus dolores ab. Beatae accusamus eos. Omnis ...", published: false, user_id: 2, created_at: "2019-01-04 06:42:20", updated_at: "2019-01-04 06:42:20">]>
```

**Mis dudas:**

- Cómo hago para activar la cache en el ambiente de desarrollo

  - Según [guides.rubyonrails.org](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) debo utilizar `rails dev:cache`, pero sigue sin funcionarme.
- Verifique la configuración de mi archivo de ../config/environments/development.rb y parece normal, a excepción de cuando utilizo la recomendacion de [guides.rubyonrails.org](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#configuration) me arroja el siguiente error.

  - `config/environments/development.rb:21:in`block in ': undefined method `megabytes' for 64:Integer (NoMethodError)`
- Cómo pruebo que rails está escribiendo en la caché?

---

**De antemano agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar**

Comment: A mí también me aparece el error `undefined method megabytes' for 64:Integer (NoMethodError)`, lo raro es que solo me falla en un proyecto de Rails. Según la documentación:

A Ruby on Rails application loads all Active Support unless config.active_support.bare is true. In that case, the application will only load what the framework itself cherry-picks for its own needs, and can still cherry-pick itself at any granularity level, as explained in the previous section.

Lograste solucionar el problema?

Comment: al vez te falte activar el cache. En ambiente de desarrollo el cache está desactivado por defecto. Se activa y desactiva usando el comando rails dev:cache. Prueba y me dices si eso te funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar el método `.read` o poner algún output dentro del bloque para verificar que esté escribiendo en caché:

```
[11] pry(main)> Rails.cache.fetch('qwer') { puts 'cacheando'; 1234 }
cacheando
=> 1234
[12] pry(main)> Rails.cache.fetch('qwer') { puts 'cacheando'; 1234 }
=> 1234
[13] pry(main)> Rails.cache.read('qwer')
=> 1234
```

Hay otros métodos más en [ActiveSupport::Cache::Store](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html) que podrían ayudarte para depurar tu problema.

Relacionado con tu error `undefined method megabytes`, no sabría decirte. Actualmente estoy trabajando con 4.2.x y me funciona, pero veo que en la última documentación de 5.2.2 sale incluido [el método que mencionas](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html). Lo que podrías hacer es usar `67108864`, que es el equivalente a 64MB:

```
[14] pry(main)> 64.megabytes
=> 67108864
```

Answer (score -1):

Para quienes no les funcione solo deben poner `true` en:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

En el archivo:

> /config/environments/development.rb